# Data changes when opening XLS file from macro

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to have a macro on workbook1 that asked the user to open a workbook (workbook2) that has only one sheet from which to copy all the data to sheet "Import" in workbook1.

My code is as follows

```
Sub test()

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim Vfile As Variant

Vfile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", 1, "The Import _
    sheet is empty, please select ME3M data to import", , False)
If Vfile = False Then Exit Sub
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(Vfile)
NewWB.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("A1")
NewWB.Close

End Sub
```

My problem is that the file I need to open is in xls and the one with the macro on (on which I want to copy the data) is in xlsx and I suspect this creates some problems because there are some cells that contain numbers the just change their value if opened through vba.

For example in one cell there is the number 1.500 (one thousand five hundred) and if I open that file the old fashion way by clicking it that's what I see; but If I get it opened by the macro by running the above code without the last two lines the number in the cell becomes 1,5 (one and a half).

Comment: This looks like a problem with your decimal separator.  Have you verified that the decimal separators are the same in both workbooks?

Comment: @jbarker2160 DecimalSeparator is an `Application` property, though... could be related though or possibly an issue with Locale settings and/or the formatting of the cell itself.

Comment: @DavidZemens, it is, but the data is still stored in that format and the localization data is stored in the document properties if you know how to retrieve it.  So... even though it's an application-level property it still has an impact on every document that is saved.

Comment: Try using: `Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Vfile, Local:=True)`

Comment: @Rory, write that up into an answer.

Comment: _"by running the above code without the last two lines"_ What happens to your numbers when you run the last two lines to actually do the import. Is the format/value of the number correct again?

Comment: @FreeMan nope... it copies it the way it appears so the wrong way. I even tried copying the hole sheet with `NewWB.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")` but it also didn't work. As soon as I can I will try Rory's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Vfile, Local:=True)
```

it should respect your local settings rather than using US settings as VBA defaults to.